# Funcion open() y metodo os.open() y derivados para archivos

Tags: python

A la hora de crear un archivo tenemos dos opciones: usar la funcion open() o utilizar el metodo del modulo os, accediendo a el con os.open().
Después tenemos sus derivados, como write, close, read; y lo mismo con el modulo os; os.write, os.read...

¿Que diferencia hay entre ambos métodos? Leyendo la documentacion oficial dice que os.open() y sus derivados son para bajo nivel, pero realmente hacen lo mismo.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Lo primero, por ser un poco más precisos, `os.open`, `os.read` y `os.write` no son métodos, son funciones en el paquete `os`</strike> (ver comentario de @ChemaCortes más abajo).

La función `open` te permite trabajar más alejado del sistema operativo en el que estés trabajando (más alto nivel) mientras que `os.open` está trabajando directamente con el sistema operativo y usando las funciones del mismo por lo que deberás escribir código un poco más específico de la plataforma en la que estés (es de más bajo nivel). El primero te permite abstraerte de ese tipo de cosas, el segundo te permite tener más control (siempre que sepas lo que estás haciendo).

`open` te devuelve un objeto que dispone de métodos que permiten manipular el objeto. Estos métodos serán unos u otros en función del modo que hayas usado para abrir el archivo (lectura, escritura,...).

`os.open` te devuelve un [*file descriptor*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptor_de_archivo) y tú serás el encargado de saber lo que has abierto, cómo lo has abierto y cómo lo debes manipular (qué funciones podrás usar sobre el mismo).

En general, deberías usar siempre `open`.

Comment: No quisiera polemizar, pero es correcto hablar de `open`, `read` y `write` como **métodos** del módulo `os`. Al importar el módulo se crea una *clausura* donde se *definen* esos métodos, similar a como se instaciaría una clase. De hecho, se crean tantas instancias del módulo como subprocesos haya.

Comment: No es polémica, es discusión y conocimiento. Si hago lo siguiente ambos `print`s me devuelven `True`: `import os, types; print(isinstance(os.open, types.BuiltinFunctionType)); print(isinstance(os.open, types.BuiltinMethodType))`. Por tanto debe ser cómo dices. He modificado la respuesta.